# Divide by 3, function in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, divide

I have a function that returns me list of int values depends on part of values:

```
private List<int> GetColumn(int total, int column)
{
    List<int> retList = new List<int>();

    if (total <= 0)
    {
        return retList;
    }

    if (column < 0 || column > 2)
    {
        column = 0;
    }

    int pageSize = total / 3;

    int startIndex = column * pageSize;
    int endIndex = column * pageSize + pageSize;

    if (endIndex > total)
    {
        endIndex = total;
    }

    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        retList.Add(i);
    }

    return retList;

}
```

but it works wrong, because for:
GetColumn(17, 0)

it returns [0,1,2,3,4], but should return [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for GetColumn(17, 1) - [6,7,8,9,10,11]
for GetColumn(17, 2) - [12,13,14,15,16]

for 16 it should return:
for GetColumn(16, 0) - [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for GetColumn(16, 1) - [6,7,8,9,10]
for GetColumn(16, 2) - [11,12,13,14,15]

What should I change in my function? Thanks!

Comment: Your first example, returns 6 elements for the (17,1) call, but 5 elements for the (17,0) and (17,2) calls. If the number of elements it's not divisible by three, how will this logic work? Should a random "page" get the extra element, or always the one in the middle? What about if there are two "extra" elements? The one in the middle and the first, or the one in the middle and the last?

Comment: `int` divided by `int` is still an `int`. At least one operand has to be `float`/`double` to make the result non-`int`.

Comment: No, it's not necessary to divide more than 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you need (numbers increase columnwise but rows need to be filled first):

```
for 16:
0  6  11
1  7  12
2  8  13
3  9  14
4  10 15
5

for 17:
0  6  12
1  7  13
2  8  14
3  9  15
4  10 16
5  11
```

You need to define which column is getting the remainders:

```
int remainder = total % 3;
```

if remainder is 1, only first column is 6 elements. if remainder is 2, first & second columns are 6 elements. You need to calculate startIndex and endIndex according to this.

So;

```
int pageSize = total / 3;
int remainder = total % 3;

int startIndex = column * pageSize + min(column, remainder);
int endIndex = startIndex + pageSize + (remainder > column ? 1 : 0);
```

should work. I just tested it, it works for different rowsizes than 3.

Here is how I got the formulas, drawing tables is good practice for sorting out such algortihms:

r:Remainder, c:column, ps:pagesize (as calculated above)

```
StartingIndex:
.  |r:0 |r:1   |r:2
----------------------
c:0|0   |0     |0
----------------------
c:1|ps  |ps+1  |ps+1
----------------------
c:2|ps*2|ps*2+1|ps*2+2
```

You can see a pattern if you extend the table for rowsize 4:

```
StartingIndex:
.  |r:0 |r:1   |r:2   |r:3
------------------------------
c:0|0   |0     |0     |0
------------------------------
c:1|ps  |ps+1  |ps+1  |ps+1
------------------------------
c:2|ps*2|ps*2+1|ps*2+2|ps*2+2
------------------------------
c:3|ps*3|ps*3+1|ps*3+2|ps*3+3
```

the value you are adding is the minimum of the related column and remainder

Similarly for the endIndex, desired columns length can be seen when you build a table for given remainder vs column. I won't write that for now because it is taking too much time to draw the tables here and I believe you already got the idea.

Comment: Yes, it exactly what I need, but how to implement in in the function to return correct range for columns 1 and 2?

Comment: Thanks, but startIndex and endIndex are wrong for different columns :(

Comment: oops! i miswrite "remainder > column" in the endIndex calculation. It should work fine now, i tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The integer division rounds to towards zero. So 17/3 = 5 and -17/3 = -5 
I think what you want is to round to the next integer like this

```
int pageSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(total / 3d);
```

Comment: in this case it doesn't work too, because for GetColumn(16, 0) it returns 5 values, but should return 6, GetColumn(16, 1) - 5, GetColumn(16, 2) - 5

Comment: It also doesn't work correct, since for 1st and 2nd columns it returns 6 values, but for third just 4, but should return: 6, 5, 5

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the requirement is:

```
If the number is 3n,   divide it in 3 groups of n,   n   and n   elements.
If the number is 3n+1, divide it in 3 groups of n+1, n   and n   elements.
If the number is 3n+2, divide it in 3 groups of n+1, n+1 and n   elements.
```

Best thing to do is to make that explicit in your code, and avoid any "clever" logic.
The straight-forward splitting boils down to:

```
If the number is 3n, the divisions are:
     0 ..  n-1
     n .. 2n-1
    2n .. 3n-1
If the number is 3n+1, the divisions are:
     0 .. n
   n+1 .. 2n
  2n+1 .. 3n
If the number is 3n+2, the divisions are:
     0 .. n
   n+1 .. 2n+1
  2n+2 .. 3n+1
```

In c# that would be something like:

```
public static List<int> Divide3Columns(int total, int column)
{
  int startIndex = 0;
  int endIndex = 0;
  int pageSize = total / 3;

  if (total % 3 == 0)
  {
    startIndex = column * pageSize;
    endIndex = (column + 1) * pageSize - 1;
  }

  if (total % 3 == 1)
  {
    if (column == 0)
    {
      startIndex = 0;
      endIndex = pageSize; //pageSize + 1 elements;
    }
    else
    {
      startIndex = column * pageSize + 1;
      endIndex = (column + 1) * pageSize;
    }
  }

  if (total % 3 == 2)
  {
    if (column == 2)
    {
      startIndex = 2 * pageSize + 2;
      endIndex = 3 * pageSize + 1; //same as total - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      startIndex = column * (pageSize + 1);
      endIndex = (column + 1) * pageSize + column;
    }
  }

  List<int> result = new List<int>();
  for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
  {
    result.Add(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

The answer assumes that we will always [divide in 3, and only 3 columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Hand_Grenade). If the number is variable, the logic to determine the columns can be generalized.

Comment: @ihorko fixed it, and added a more complete example